# Openpyxl won't load my workbook

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I am trying to open a rather large .xlsx file using openpyxl, and the load_workbook function, but for some reason the file I want to open will not open, and instead will error out.

```
wb=openpyxl.load_workbook(laneReport)
print(laneReport)
```

I expect the output from this to be the name of the file I want to open, but instead I get an error message.

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
File "C:\Users\tamimia\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\descriptors\base.py", line 57, in _convert
value = expected_type(value)
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '#REF!'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/tamimia/Documents/Py/jfu/LaneAnalysis.py", line 55, in <module>
main()
File "C:/Users/tamimia/Documents/Py/jfu/LaneAnalysis.py", line 50, in main
x.checkHeader(laneReport)
File "C:/Users/tamimia/Documents/Py/jfu/LaneAnalysis.py", line 32, in checkHeader
wb=openpyxl.load_workbook(laneReport)
File "C:\Users\tamimia\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 245, in load_workbook
ws_parser.parse()
File "C:\Users\tamimia\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\worksheet.py", line 127, in parse
dispatcher[tag_name](element)
File "C:\Users\tamimia\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\worksheet.py", line 286, in parser_conditional_formatting
cf = ConditionalFormatting.from_tree(element)
File "C:\Users\tamimia\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\descriptors\serialisable.py", line 79, in from_tree
obj = desc.expected_type.from_tree(el)
File "C:\Users\tamimia\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\descriptors\serialisable.py", line 79, in from_tree
obj = desc.expected_type.from_tree(el)
File "C:\Users\tamimia\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\descriptors\serialisable.py", line 79, in from_tree
obj = desc.expected_type.from_tree(el)
File "C:\Users\tamimia\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\descriptors\serialisable.py", line 92, in from_tree
return cls(**attrib)
File "C:\Users\tamimia\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\formatting\rule.py", line 60, in __init__
self.val = val
File "C:\Users\tamimia\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\formatting\rule.py", line 39, in __set__
super(ValueDescriptor, self).__set__(instance, value)
File "C:\Users\tamimia\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\descriptors\base.py", line 69, in __set__
value = _convert(self.expected_type, value)
File "C:\Users\tamimia\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\descriptors\base.py", line 59, in _convert
raise TypeError('expected ' + str(expected_type))
TypeError: expected <class 'float'>
```

Comment: looks like a bug in openpyxl, not being able to open sheets with unknown references to a cell.

Comment: If not already done , try updating `openpyxl` to latest. And also use `pandas` or some other module to load workbook and see if that works. That may help in isolating problem.